# Function that give the number of words

Tags: python, string, search, words

I'm doing a function that give the number of words in a sentence.
Example: "   Hello L World   " there are 3 "words" (A letter is counted like a word).

Here is my code:

```
def number_of_word(s):
"""
   str -> int
    """
# i : int
i = 0

# nb_word : int
nb_word = 0

if s == "":
    return 0
else:

    while i < len(s)-1:
        if ((s[i] != " ") and (s[i+1] == " ")):
            nb_word = nb_word + 1
            i = i + 1
        else:
            i = i + 1

    if s[len(s)-1] != " ":
        nb_word = nb_word + 1
        return nb_word
    else:
        return nb_word
```

I tried my function and I think it works. But, I also think there is a better way to do a function that do the same thing in an easier way.

Can you tell me if you know one better function? Or any comments on mine?

I hade to use:

```
if s == "":
    return 0
else:
      ...........
```

because if I didn't, my function didn't work for `number_of_word("")`

Answer (score 4):

If you define words as character sequences separated by one or more whitespaces, then you can simply use the `split` method of strings to split to words,
and then `len` to get their count:

```
def number_of_word(s):
    return len(s.split())
```

From the documentation (emphasis mine):

> `split(...)` method of `builtins.str` instance
>
> `S.split(sep=None, maxsplit=-1)` -> list of strings
>
> Return a list of the words in `S`, using `sep` as the delimiter string. 
>   If `maxsplit` is given, at most `maxsplit` splits are done. **If `sep` is not
>   specified or is `None`, any whitespace string is a separator and empty
>   strings are removed from the result.**

Answer (score 2):

If you want you can use `RegExp`

```
import re

def number_of_word(s):
    pattern = r'\b\w+\b'
    return len(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use split or regex, I think this is the right solution:

```
def count(sentence):
    wlist = []
    word = ""
    for c in sentence:
        if c == " ":
            wlist.append(word)
            word = ""
        else:
            word += c
    wlist.append(word)
    return len(wlist)
```

Comment: If you just need to count words, why do you create a list of words?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split()` method :

```
def count(string1):
    string1=string1.split()
    return len(string1)
print(count(" Hello L World "))
```

output:

```
3
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't use more python' functions than just "len". 
So, I can't use split or RegExp.

So I want to make this function with just basic code and len.

Comment: Make an edit to your question  instead of answering to your question

Answer (score 0):

Well, since the requirements were published, here's a way to do this without calling any library functions:

```
def count_words(sentence):
    count, white = 0, True
    for character in sentence:
        if character not in " \t\n\r":
            if white:
                count += 1
                white = False
        else:
            white = True
    return count
```